# Is it possible to use the glyph from an emoji in a Buffered Image in Java?

Tags: java, emoji

I'm trying to write text, including emoji, to a BufferedImage object in java.
I have coloured emoji fonts installed on my development machine, which is running Ubuntu 19.10, and the emoji appear coloured in the terminal, but in the image, they appear as outlines, like wireframe.

Is it possible to have them appear as in the terminal, or am I limited to the wireframe appearance?

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(EmojiOnImage.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/background.png"));
Graphics2D graphics = backgroundImage.createGraphics();
Font EMOJI_FONT = new Font("Noto Emoji", Font.BOLD, 14);
graphics.setFont(EMOJI_FONT);
String emoji = "  ";
graphics.drawString(goalEmoji, bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

ive been trying something similar for my 3D Rendering Engine.
Using Emoji based textures, generated at runtime for the toolbar or some other glyph-based UI-hints instead of just plain old text.
My findings come pretty much to the conclusion that the utf encoding of an emoji is os-specificly implemented and the console returns the results accordingly.
Rendering/Drawing emojis to a buffered image doesnt work apparently, as the string encoding is done on java-side and java (im using java-8-261) doesnt support emoji rendering as its not encoded within the library.

my next guess, but i havent tried it yet, is to render the emoji within the "hidden" console, read the string in already as a new bufferedimage already containing the imagedata instead of something like this >>Font.decode("\u26D3");<<